# Is this possible to declare a php variable which can store more than 512 characters

Tags: php

The scenario looks like this

```
$data=$_REQUEST['data'];
echo $data
the url is www.mysite.com/service.php?data=
 and the possible value for the key will be `100005772653,0|102795882836,0|100005772653,0|102795882836,0|100005772653,0|102795882836,0|100005772653,0|102795882836,0|100005772653,0|102795882836,0|100005772653,0|102795882836,0|100005772653,0|102795882836,0|100005772653,0|102795882836,0|100005772653,0|102795882836,0|100005772653,0|102795882836,0|100005772653,0|102795882836,0|100005772653,0|102795882836,0|100005772653,0|102795882836,0|100005772653,0|102795882836,0|100005772653,0|102795882836,0|100005772653,0|102795882836,0`
```

I am writing a simple Insert query. The code fails when the length of the data field exceeds 512 characters. So this situation provoked me to post such a question with limit value.

If i echo the **$data** it just shows a null (empty data).  If the given data is less then it gets inserted.

Comment: There is no 512 character limit on a php string

Comment: Please post the code that gives you this error! Also, the error message itself!

Comment: are you getting the variable value from a MySQL `varchar` field by any chance ?

Comment: I doubt his string must be breaking because of quotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Who said PHP can only store 512 characters? you are doing something wrong, you can store whatever amount of data you want to store in a variable..

As Alvin Wong Shared A [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), it says PHP `string` can be as large as 2GB

Test Case, Try to run this

```
<?php
   $string = 'Blah blah';
   for($i=1; $i<=10000; $i++) {
    $string .= 'Blah blah';
   }
   echo $string;
?>
```

Comment: You may like to add that [PHP string can be as large as 2GB.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Or even run this: http://pastebin.com/GK8FhsdY and see where it breaks.  (Be prepared to hose your system while it runs.)

Comment: @ghoti 423400 bytes at least, but can't test more because of timeout http://codepad.org/2qF2BLUa

Comment: @lalith222 you asked wrongly, yes there's a limit for GET, you can use post instead

Comment: @AlvinWong - I hit my `php.memory_limit` at 128MB in shell on my workstation.  I won't bother testing further.  :)

Comment: @ghoti haha that was a beast code..and (lalith222) I didn't said use `$_POST` only for retrieving the data, also use it for posting, there's no way you cannot post this string using POST method